# Advice on new project: additional functionality into existing ASP.NET app

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis

Looking for suggestions regarding an upcoming project that I am involved in which revolves around adding certain functionality to an existing ASP.NET application running on IIS 6.0 programmed in VB.NET.

To aid in future development the client wants the additional functionality to be as future proof as possible. Ideally I have said that I would like to push for a solution using ASP.NET MVC3, running off IIs 7.5 and .NET 4, written in C#. This solution would act as a seamless addition to the current web-portal appearing probably just as an extra tabbed page.

But they will be completely separate web-apps. Which is crucial.

The main problems I can foresee are firstly sharing session particulars between the asp.net web app and the new application. Particularly with regard to maintaining session state (and not having IIS timing out on one of the apps). Also, conjoining the two "apps" appears problematic in my head, although this may be far simpler than I fear.

I'm asking for suggestions for these two problems if anyone has any ideas please say!

So far I've come up with the following solutions be they terrible or not:

1) Embed the new functionality into the existing codebase (not a great option). This would mean losing any potential future upgrade-ability and also means not following better OO conventions by utilising the MVC framework.

2) Using an iFrame to link to the razor pages of a seperate MVC3 app (the one I'm favouring currently). Allows uses of all new technologies, however downside is sharing session data. Either through iFrame "attributes" (is this possible?) through persisting a session state to a db? (slow?) or even some kind of web service interaction between the applications to push/pull user/session data?

Any advice/suggestions greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you that C# and MVC is the "way to go", but unfortunately mixing two applications together is going to give you a whole bunch of headaches, not least the different session IDs.  You'd probably have to have a shared database table to map them together and, as you can probably imagine already this reeks of "Band-aid".

What are the ramifications in rebuilding what is existing, in to C#?  Perhaps you could suggest a complete upgrade.  The client themselves seem to extol the virtues of future-proofing and therefore this would be the way to go.  And no, I wouldn't promote the use of a "code-converter", but it really shouldn't be that difficult.

The next thing to consider, I guess, is "future-proof".  Is the client worried that VB.NET is going to disappear any-time soon or that it cannot handle anything in the future?  I find that a very unlikely scenario, honestly.

I think I've waffled on a bit, but essentially combining two applications, one with old and one with new functionality will cause a headaches.  This could be solved by migrating the old site to C#/MVC, and then adding the extra functionality.  True, this may seem like a large commitment today - but further on down the road, it will pay dividends.

Comment: Agreed, however upgrading the existing app is not possible for the current remit of the contract. What i need to do is isolate the potential headaches and provide work-arounds

Answer (score 0):

If the current site can be upgrade to .NET 4.0 there's no reason why you wouldn't extend the existing application.

There's nothing to stop you mixing MVC and web forms (indeed there are several articles on how to do just this). There's nothing to stop you mixing VB.NET and C# (or, so far as I'm aware, to stop you doing MVC in VB.NET).

You'd have to work very hard to convince me of the merits of using iFrames. Very hard. You might be able to persuade me of the merits of running two applications side by side - with the functionality split by folder - but to be honest I'd be much happier upgrading the existing site and then building from there.

Comment: Same comment as for Moo-Juice really, upgrading the site is not an option, so issues and solutions for working with what we have is what im after

Comment: Ok, I do not understand that. Not at all. Are you saying that you have no access to the source for the current application? You're going to be stuffed on session sync then... I do appreciate that we're often put in situations that seem nonsensical when viewed from outside but equally that can be a flag that something has to change.

Comment: Correct I will not have access to the source. The client has viewed this as a standalone app that will be tacked on to provide additional functionality. The proposed method of maintaining session sync currently would be either a web service to enact some form of push/pull notifications between the apps, potentially peristing some session infor to a db (timeout etc). Does that not sound viable to you?

Comment: @MattTolliday It sounds like an absolute nightmare to be honest - oh I'm sure it can be made to work, I've done something vaguely similar - but I think it sits in direct contradiction to "as future proof as possible" when one would expect it to be possible to migrate the existing app to at least .NET 3.5 without too much grief.